# R Code: non negative solution that satisfy n matrix equations

Tags: r, math, matrix

It is a matrix question where I'm trying to solve for a best fit non negative x that would satisfy 2 or more matrix equations. I am able to solve for the equations individually, but I am clueless as how to solve for all *'n'* matrices simultaneously.

> **A**x - c = **B**x - d = **E**x - f = ... = **0**

Below I have 2 groups of Matrices which I solve individually.

> **A**x = c
>
> **B**y = d

There is no constraint on x = y

```
require(pracma)
require(corpcor)
require(NMF)

mat=c(0.005,0.006,0.002,0,0,0,0,
      0,0.005,0.006,0.002,0,0,0,
      0,0,0.005,0.006,0.002,0,0,
      0,0,0,0.005,0.006,0.002,0,
      0,0,0,0,0.005,0.006,0.002,
      0,0,0,0,0,0.005,0.006,
      0.003,0.004,0.002,0,0,0,0,
      0,0.003,0.004,0.002,0,0,0,
      0,0,0.003,0.004,0.002,0,0,
      0,0,0,0.003,0.004,0.002,0,
      0,0,0,0,0.003,0.004,0.002,
      0,0,0,0,0,0.003,0.004     
)
mat = matrix(mat,byrow=T,ncol=7)
rownames(mat) = rep(c("Group A", "Group B"), times = c(6,6))

mat.A = mat[rownames(mat) == "Group A",]
mat.B = mat[rownames(mat) == "Group B",]

y.A = sample(c(100:500), 7)
y.B = sample(c(200:300), 7)

# Solve B
a = t(mat.A)
b = as.numeric(y.A)

Test.a  = qr(a, tol = 0.0000001)
nc = ncol(Test.a$qr)
nr = nrow(Test.a$qr)
if (Test.a$rank != min(nc, nr)){
  x = ceiling(fcnnls(a,b, pseudo = T)$x)
} else x = ceiling(lsqnonneg(a,b)$x)

# Solve A 
a = t(mat.B)
b = as.numeric(y.B)

Test.a  = qr(a, tol = 0.0000001)
nc = ncol(Test.a$qr)
nr = nrow(Test.a$qr)
if (Test.a$rank != min(nc, nr)){
  x = ceiling(fcnnls(a,b, pseudo = T)$x)
} else x = ceiling(lsqnonneg(a,b)$x)
```

Answer (score 8):

We assume that "best fit" means finding the non-negative `x` which minimizes:

> ||**A**x - c||<sup>2</sup> + ||**B**x - d||<sup>2</sup>

We can compute that using the nnls package.  Assuming that `mat` is the matrix composed of `A`'s rows stacked on top of `B`'s rows, i.e. `rbind(A, B)`, and that `c` and `d` are both vectors of ones so that `c(c, d)` is a vector of `nrow(mat)` ones we have:

```
library(nnls)
nnls(mat, rep(1, nrow(mat)))
```

giving:

```
Nonnegative least squares model
x estimates: 82.87176 83.51637 104.6671 52.97634 148.3001 0 193.7866 
residual sum-of-squares: 0.39
reason terminated: The solution has been computed sucessfully.
```